# how to request url to connect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, url

how to request url to execute or connect to server ..
what i was using not working..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",[ConfigDB valueForKey:@"mailURL"], @"?ownerID=", [ConfigDB ownerID], @"&userid=",[ConfigDB userID],@"&pID=",pid,@"&emailAddress=",emailTxtField.text,[ConfigDB valueForKey:@"showEmailFlag"]]]; 


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
```

Comment: Might want to clean up the URLWithString parameter by using stringWithFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a `stringWithFormat` message!  The first thing to check is that you're getting a URL that matches your expectations.

Once you've got a URL request object—and consider using a regular `NSURLRequest`, it should be faster and it doesn't look like you're intending to reuse this object:

```
// already autoreleased
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Then you need to actually make the request.  There are two approaches here.  You'll use `NSURLDownload` if you're looking to save the request to file.  It looks like you're looking to make a `GET` request to an email server of some sort, so you probably want the other approach: `NSURLConnection`.

`NSURLConnection` is mostly intended for asynchronous requests.  You provide a delegate with some methods and your NSURLConnection will use those methods to let you  know when the communication is done; whether there were errors; etc.

Add a property to your view controller class for the connection, and an `NSMutableData` property as well.  You will start your connection with (assuming that your current class is also your delegate):

```
// initialize our storage for the file
self.downloadData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:1024];
// create and start the connection
self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(nil == self.urlConnection) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create connection to url %@", url);
}
```

In your code somewhere—probably your current view controller—you'll need to implement those methods:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    // if you have more than one NSURLConnection in this class, test against the 
    // connection parameter

    [downloadData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
    // download completed successfully, we can do what we like with the downloadData object now
    // ...
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
    // handle failure with the grace of Audrey Hepburn.  probably log something, too
}
```